Select records from DB table while checking OPENJSON value
If I had a db table with:
(Details being a JSON string)
Id   Details                             Price
1   {"partNumber":"012345","qty":14}    14.99
2   {"partNumber":"22222","qty":11}     4.88
3   {"partNumber":"44444","qty":1}      3.24
4   {"partNumber":"72431223","qty":9}   3.33
5   {"partNumber":"98989","qty":1}      3.33

and I only wanted to return records where the quantity (qty) is 1.
So only return record with id 1 and 3.
So far I have got
select * from tableName where ('1') IN (select qty from OPENJSON(tableName.Details) WITH ( [qty]  NVARCHAR(20) '$.qty'))

which is correctt, but what if I wanted to change the qty to return results with a quantity less than 10, so I would get records with id 3, 4 and 5 returned

Why do you use NVARCHAR(20) for your OPENJSON column, if you want to compare integers. Also, use CROSS APPLY OPENJSON, your version looks horrible

Try cross-apply.
The OPENJSON operator expands the JSON array of tableName Details as if the Details were stored in a separate child table. Then the CROSS APPLY operator joins each Details row to the rows returned by the OPENJSON table-valued function.
SELECT *
FROM tableName  
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(tableName.Details) WITH (qty NVARCHAR(20) '$.qty')
WHERE qty < 10


excellent thanks for taking the time to reply
